# How can I deploy my raft orderer nodes on separate hosts?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, consensus, raft

I'm using HyperLedger Fabric(v1.4.1) on 3 host machines(server1:client, server2:peer nodes server3:orderer nodes).
And I want to put my raft nodes on multiple hosts.(like server1:orderer1,orderer2,  server2:orderer3)

I edited docker-compose-cli.yaml below

```
 extra hosts: (in client and peer)
  - orderer1.example.com:${SERVER1}
  - orderer2.example.com:${SERVER1}
  - orderer3.example.com:${SERVER2}

 extra hosts: (in orderer1,2)
  - orderer3.example.com:${SERVER2}

 extra hosts: (in orderer3)
  - orderer1.example.com:${SERVER1}
  - orderer2.example.com:${SERVER1}
```

in this case,I got that messages like this from orderer3 logs...

**

> **'Failed to send StepRequest to 2, because: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns  are  TransientFailure , latest
>   connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: authentication
>   handshake failed: x509: certificate is valid for orderer1.example.com,
>   orderer1, not orderer2.example.com" '**

**

What should I do except docker-compose-cli.yaml configurations?

Thank you very mutch for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

you should also make change on configtx.yaml.